Max supply of smallest divisible unit vs largest integer
Does Ethereum have a total supply, expressed in its smallest unit (1 wei*), that is equal to its largest numeric value (uint256*)?
If yes/no: is it typical for decentralised currencies to have a large/smaller/equal amount of its smallest tokens compared to the max number in its underlying language?
(I know it is not feasible to answer this second part of the question for every decentralised currency, though I would expect for the largest X% marketcap, there may be some similiarities with respect to this property).
** Assumptions

I assume the smallest divisible amount of Ethereum is 1 wei.
I assume the largest numeric value permitted within Solidity (that can be stored in a single variable as a number), is a uint256.


First Part of the Question
No , Ethereum does not have a total supply equal to its largest numeric value in uint256
Eth does not have a fixed total supply. Unlike Bitcoin, which has a maximum supply cap , Eth supply increases over time due to mining rewards and other mechanisms.
At this time ,Eth supply is like 120M which is like 1.2×10^26 wei, and if we want to compare it with the maximum value of uint256 which is like around 2^256
Total eth supply in wei = 1.2×10^26 wei 
Maximum value of uint256  = 2^256 - 1  
We can see that the total supply is way less than the maximum value of uint256
In practical terms it is impossible for eth supply to reach somewhere close to 2^256 wei . But if it reaches it will cause issues , but its impossible so its irrelevant
Second Part of the Question
Some decentralized currencies, like Bitcoin, have a fixed maximum supply like i said earlier while some others, like Ethereum, do not have a fixed supply and continue to grow over time.
The total supply of Bitcoin (21 million) is much smaller than the maximum value of uint256 and also for most decentralized currencies, the total supply (expressed in their smallest units) tends to be much smaller than the maximum numeric value allowed by uint256
